# Can not set value for Antd Datepicker from API call with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, dayjs

I am using react and antd for my side project.I am able to set the data with selection from antd Datepicker. With every change, I am updating sessionStorage.The problem starts here.After filling the form, when User refreshes the page, other form areas are filled with the value from sessionStorage. But datepicker throws error `date.locale is not a function at Object.format (dayjs.js:185:19)` like this.Is there a way to solve this issue? I searched some posts but I am not able to solve the problem.

This is the date value at sessionStorage.Whenever I try to refresh the page I am getting the error of `date.locale is not a function`
[image: ERROR]

[image: Session Storage]

I have a parent component Navigation.tsx

```js
import HotelAndDate from "./HotelAndDate";
import { Steps, message, Form } from 'antd'
import Button from 'antd/es/button';
import RoomDetails from "./RoomDetails";
import Payment from "./Payment";
import './index.css'
import { useNavigation } from "./useNavigation";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSessionStorage } from "./useSessionStorage";
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs'
dayjs().format()

export type FormT = {
    hotel_name: string
    startDate: string
    endDate: string
    parents: number
    children: number
}


const initialData: FormT = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('formData') || '{}') || {
    hotel_name: '',
    startDate: '2022-12-22',
    endDate: '',
    parents: 0,
    children: 0
};


function Navigation() {
    const [data, setData] = useSessionStorage<FormT[] | FormT>('formData', initialData);
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    useEffect(() => {
        let storedData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('formData') || '{}');
        setData(storedData);
    }, []);
    console.log('SSS', data);


    const onFinish = async () => {
        const values = await form.validateFields();
        console.log(values);
    }


    var INITIAL_STEPS = [
        {
            title: 'Hotel And Date',
            content: <HotelAndDate data={data} setData={setData} updateFields={updateForm} />,
        },
        {
            title: 'Room Details',
            content: <RoomDetails />,
        },
        {
            title: 'Payment',
            content: <Payment />,
        },
    ];

    const { current, step, steps, next, prev, goTo, isFirstStep, isLastStep } = useNavigation(INITIAL_STEPS)
    const items = steps.map((item) => ({ key: item.title, title: item.title }));

    function updateForm(fields: Partial<FormT>): void {
        setData(prev => {
            return { ...prev, ...fields }
        })
    }

    function handlePreviousClick() {
        prev();
    }

    return (
        <div className=" mx-auto flex max-w-7xl  p-6 lg:px-8" style={{ flexDirection: 'column', rowGap: '2rem' }}>
            <Steps current={current} items={items} labelPlacement='vertical'></Steps>
            <Form layout="vertical" initialValues={initialData} onFinish={onFinish} >
                {steps[current].content}
            </Form>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                {!isFirstStep && (
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="button" onClick={handlePreviousClick}> Previous</Button>
                )}
                {current < steps.length - 1 && (
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="button" onClick={next}>Next</Button>
                )}
                {isLastStep && (
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={() => message.success('Processing complete!')}>
                        Done
                    </Button>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And my child component => HotelAndDate.tsx ( Where the problem comes from )

```js
function HotelAndDate({ data, setData, updateFields }: { data: any, setData: any, updateFields: any }) {
  const { hotelListLoading, hotels } = useGetHotelList();
  return (
    <Row gutter={[32, 32]} justify="space-between">
     {/* other form areas */}
      <Col >
        <Form.Item name="startDate" label="Start Date" rules={[{ required: true }]}>
          <DatePicker  value={dayjs("")} onChange={(date,dateString) => date && updateFields({ startDate:  dateString})} placeholder="Start Date" />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
     {/* other form areas */}
    </Row>
  )
}

export default HotelAndDate;
```